# WAMP and PEAR PHP version change, PEAR Version doesn't match

Tags: php, wamp, pear

I just installed a fresh copy of WAMP server on Windows. I'm trying to get PEAR working and have never used it before. After i Installed WAMP i changed the PHP version to 7.1.9 (there are 3 options available in WAMP including

```
5.6.31
7.0.23
7.1.9
```

c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9. NOTE: i did place the go-pear.phar file INSIDE the directory of PHP that is currently active in wamp (7.1.9). From the console i then ran from that directory command:

```
php go-pear.phar
```

PEAR installing starts running and asks some questions, i choose local version (i have since tried system-wide and have the same problems, not sure what the diff is), answer the rest of Q's seems ok

But then when i try to install a package with PECL with command:

```
pecl install libsodium
```

i get the following error:

```
pecl/libsodium requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0, version <= 7.99.99), installed version is 5.6.31
No valid packages found
install failed
```

When i run command "PHP -v" i get

```
PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2017 18:34:46) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
```

But when i run command pecl version i get

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.5
PHP Version: 5.6.31
Zend Engine Version: 2.6.0
Running on: Windows NT DESKTOP-RBRGO97 10.0 build 16299 (Windows 10) AMD64
```

How the heck can i change the PECL PHP version? i can't find any info on this problem anywhere and i can't find a command for it. I ran config-show and everything seems ok (as far as i know) except for the extension directory is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: I've since learned that the version showing in my console of PHP is not the same as running in Apache. For example if i call phpinfo() on page it tells me the correct version 7.1.9 But how do I tell PEAR to change the version in console?

Comment: I guess no one understands this either. I've since tried using XAMMP instead, which allows you only 1 PHP version in the build so solves that problem, but I ran into a different problem so I grew tired of Windows and am starting a new Virtual Machine of my own using VirtualBox. Its tricky setting it up i definitely recommend this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fy0MuysJU5Q and you will need to find a tutorial on setting up a LAMP.